# Why do these laurent series approaches conflict?

Tags: complex-analysis, laurent-series

I was working on a problem of finding the Laurent series of $\frac{1}{z-3}$ that converges where $|z-4| > 1$

So I had one approach, let $u=z-4$ then:

$$\frac{1}{z-3} = \frac{1}{1+u} $$

$$ = \frac{1}{u} - \frac{1}{u^2} +  \frac{1}{u^3}...$$

$$ =  \frac{1}{z-4} -  \frac{1}{(z-4)^2} +  ...$$

But this apparently incorrect.

The correct answer is found by noting:

$$ \frac{1}{z-3} = \frac{1}{z-4 + 1} = \frac{1}{z-4} \frac{1}{1 - \frac{-1}{z-4}} = -\frac{1}{(z-4)^2} + ... $$

Where did I go wrong?

Comment: Your first one is correct.  $\frac {1}{z-3} = \frac {1}{z-4} - \frac {1}{(z-4)^2} + \cdots$  Try evaluating $z = 6\cdots \frac {1}{3} = \frac 12 - \frac 14 + \frac 18-\cdots$

Comment: The Princeton review book says the first term is of order 2, and they make... you know what I think they are plain wrong here. Since their factorization introduces a first order term in either expansion direction

Answer (score 1):

${1\over 1+x} = 1 - x + x^2 - x^3 + \cdots$ when $|x| < 1$.

This is derived from ${1 \over 1-x} = 1 + x + x^2 + \cdots$ with $|x| < 1$.

Comment: i.e. the first is incorrect because the Taylor expansion is wrong.

Comment: I’m not sure I understand. I’m using the formula for $|x|>1$

Comment: @frogeyedpeas I believe that is the expansion of $\frac{1}{1+ {1\over u}}$

Comment: You can also use this formula, but remember to divide $u$ on both sides.

Comment: It’s one of 2 expansions. $\frac{1}{1+x} = \frac{1}{x}-\frac{1}{x^2} + ...$

Comment: That’s the one I’m going after

Answer (score 1):

$$
\begin{align}
\frac1{z-4}\frac1{1+\frac1{z-4}}
&=\frac1{z-4}\left(1-\frac1{z-4}+\frac1{(z-4)^2}-\dots\right)\\
&=\frac1{z-4}-\frac1{(z-4)^2}+\frac1{(z-4)^3}-\dots
\end{align}
$$
The series starts with $\frac1{z-4}$, not $\frac1{(z-4)^2}$.